# Powershell: Alternative to NoNewLine?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, newline

I have a script working that uses a hashtable for storing and comparing values, and then it writes the output to a text file. Here is an example of what happens with and without NoNewLine in my output:

With NoNewLine:

```
All servers are all on Version 19.1.5
```

Without NoNewLine:

```
All server are all on 
Version 19.1.5
```

So, NoNewLine solved that problem, but I had been testing it on a server that had Powershell 5.0. When I tested it on another server, Powershell didn't recognize NoNewLine because it was on version 4.0. Getting all of the servers on a newer version of PS unfortunately isn't an option, so is there an easy way to do a NoNewLine equivalent that older PS versions can handle? I've been googling this for a while but haven't found any good substitutes. I tried doing the whole "n`r`" thing but couldn't get it to work. Here is my code that uses NoNewLine:

```
if (@($TableVersion.Values | Group-Object).Count -eq 1) {
    if (@($TableHash.Values | Group-Object).Count -eq 1) {
        Write-Output "The servers are all on " $TableVersion.Serverapps01 | Out-File D:\Results$Timestamp.txt -NoNewline;
        }
    else {
        Write-Output "The servers are all on " $TableVersion.Serverapps01 " but there are differences in the build files." | Out-File D:\Results$Timestamp.txt -NoNewline;
    }
}
else {
    @(Write-Output "The server versions do not match: "
    $TableVersion.GetEnumerator() | Sort -Property Name | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders) | Out-File D:\Results$Timestamp.txt;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just send a single string to `Out-File`:

```
Write-Output "The servers are all on $($TableVersion.Serverapps01) but there are differences in the build files." |Out-File D:\Results$Timestamp.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I actually tried something similar before, but I didn't realize you had to wrap the variable in $(). Why is that?

Comment: Otherwise `Write-Output` will see the 2 or 3 strings as separate arguments. The subexpression operator (`$()`) just expands the expression inside the same string instead and `Write-Output` only sees 1 argument :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a string and the `-f` (format) operator:

```
"The servers are all on {0} but there are differences in the build files." -f $TableVersion.Serverapps01 | Out-File D:\Results$Timestamp.txt
```

`Write-Output` is fine but unnecessary.